# Express.js have problem with path url including ‘?’

Tags: javascript, html, forms, express, form-submit

Express.js doesn't take `?` in the path URL.

How can I solve this problem?

When I hit the submit button, I get this:

```
http://localhost:1000/register?username=test&password=test123
```

However, it's the same as:

```
http://localhost:1000/register
```

I have searched a lot about how I can fix the problem with the `?`in the URL path. And there is a lot of answers. But I only got a decent knowledge with Express and JavaScript. So I need a simple answer

Do I need to do something with my `<form></form>` element? Or do I have to fix the way I use the `app.get();` method?

Express server

```js
app.get('/register?username=:username&password=:password', function(req, res) {
    console.log('/register=?');
});

app.get('/register', function(req, res) {
    console.log('/register);
});
```

HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="register">
                <h1>Register</h1>
                <form runat="server">
                    <label for="username">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" />
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have to use `req.query` property

Comment: `?` is NOT part of the path of the request and when using Express, you can't put `?` into a route path.  It will never match if you do.  In URLs, the `?` and the things that come after it are called the query parameter.  You match the route with the path and then you access the query parameters with `req.query` and act accordingly.  If you're trying to make a different route handler based on the query parameters, then you're probably designing it wrong as that's now how URLs or route handlers are generally designed. Inside your route handler, you can branch with code based on query parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access query string parameters via the `req.query` property, for example:

```
app.get('/register', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.query); // { username : 'test', password: 'test123' }
    console.log('/register);
});
```

From the documentation:

> This property is an object containing a property for each query string parameter in the route. If there is no query string, it is the empty object, `{}`.

See:  https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query

You can also remove the first handler in your server side code where it seems you are trying to also use `req.params`.

`req.params` can be used like this in a route handler:

```
api/:api_version/songs
```

Then your URL could be something like:

```
api/v1/songs?artist=abba
// req.params.api_version is ‘v1’  
// req.query.artist is ‘abba’
```

See:  https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.params